# Angular 5 check property changed value on interval and set new css class

Tags: angular

I have a list of objects which are displayed with ngFor and all of them have a due date. What I have to do is to check every 30 seconds whether the due date expired and if it expired to add a red flag on it. Any suggestions in how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TS** code

In a `setInterval` iterate through array items and update a certain attribute (`expired`) in items that have expired.

**HTML**

Then do a `[ngClass]` binding to that `expired` attribute.